# Can a HTML table in Vue be rendered from this Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, api, vue.js

I'm working in **Vue** to make a table of data from a called API, I have this Javascript code which successfully returns back the data in Chrome's console:

```
import JQuery from 'jquery'
let $ = JQuery

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", function(data){
        var employeeData = '';

        console.log(data);

        $.each(data, function(key, value){
            employeeData += '<tr>';
            employeeData += '<td>'+value.userId+'</td>';
            employeeData += '<td>'+value.id+'</td>';
            employeeData += '<td>'+value.title+'</td>';
            employeeData += '<td>'+value.body+'</td>';

            employeeData += '<tr>';
        });
        $('#tracerouteTable').append(employeeData);
    });
});
```

How do I go about writing this in Vue's template tags to render this table with v-for?

Comment: Is this jQuery code you're attempting to translate into Vue, or is this your attempt at Vue code? If the former, you should show us what you attempted in Vue. If the latter, you've misunderstood the point of Vue.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it totally wrong - you don't need jQuery for this.
I've example for you

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    users: []
  },
  
  created() {
   axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
     .then(response => this.users = response.data)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>E-Mail</th>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
      <td>{{user.name}}</td>
      <td>{{user.email}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly..  I'd start by learning what VUE is and how it works. Its well documented.